# How can I create new variable using value + string?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having issues with this specific question for an assignment.  How do I pull the value from the num_favorite_actors column and create the new column in the middle that is [num_favorite_actors + 'multiple actors']?

Table and question:

[image]

My current query:

```
SELECT a.customer_name, num_favorite_actor ||' multiple actors'|| as favorite_actor, num_favorite_actor FROM customer_actor3 AS a
```

Comment: What's wrong with `SELECT column FROM table WHERE condition`?

Comment: In this I'm not just filtering rows on a condition, I'm creating a new column that pulls the value from a different column + a string.   Values should read 'x multiple actors' where x is value from different column.    

I'm sure this is simple.  I just haven't had to create a varchar column like that previously

Comment: It's unclear. Your screenshot of your homework assignment shows the table has 3 columns, so I'd select one of those. Where do you need to create a table/column?

Comment: Ahh, I should have specified.  The middle column (favorite_actor) is a the column that needs to be created using the num_favorite_actor column.   So favorite_actor = num_favorite_actor + 'multiple actors'

Comment: Which part is unclear? Selecting the value, naming the column, concatenating strings (which dbms, every vendor has a different syntax), filtering the data, creating the table, inserting into the table? What is your current query and how does it not give the expected result?

Comment: SELECT a.customer_name, 
num_favorite_actor ||' multiple actors'|| as favorite_actor,
num_favorite_actor
FROM customer_actor3 AS a

Comment: That's the code I just attempted to run, getting an error on the line where I attempt to concatenate - I guess this isn't technically concatenating since I'm not joining two columns, just pulling a value from one and adding a string after the value.   Thank you, btw

Comment: Can you please provide the table and question as text, not as an image? You can [edit (change) your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69872600/edit). (But please do it without "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written today.) Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`||` is the string concatenation operator. It needs two operands.

`num_favorite_actor ||' multiple actors'||` has a second operator without a RHS operand. Consider the math expression `1 + 2 +` – it is invalid in the exact same way.

```
SELECT a.customer_name, num_favorite_actor ||' multiple actors' AS favorite_actor, num_favorite_actor
FROM customer_actor3 AS a
```

Comment: *facepalm*.  Dude.  Thank you.  I am clearly learning SQL, but enjoying it so far.